# How to integerate Mpesa Api with android

Tags: java, php, android

I am making loan app. and I am stuck on this How to Integrate  MPESA because I live outside Africa.

Here is the link [PESAPI](http://www.pesapi.com/howto.html). I am done with step 3 but now I cant understand what to do next.

Q 1) Can I integrate it with my Loan app android ?

Q 2) What to do next please guide me I am stuck on this from last one weak.

Comment: I am making this for my client who lives in AFRICA

Comment: you can call a web application hosting the API at that juncture and achieve the same.

Comment: @nafeesahmed did you find solution for this. my head is burning out men

Answer (score 2):

If you are still interested, Safaricom recently introduced a [REST based interface](https://developer.safaricom.co.ke/) for consumption of MPesa APIs. They have documentation there, and a pretty good tutorial on how to use it can be found [here](https://peternjeru.co.ke/safdaraja/ui/). For using on your app, you will need a back-end interface to act as a mediator to MPesa, as most of their APIs are asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Pesa pi cannot be used for the intended purpose. What pesapi does is take  confirmation message from your android mobile and pushes that message to your application.

Message in this context is a message that mpesa sends to the registered mobile number of the payee once a payment is done via lipa na mpesa and pay bill.

What Mutwiri was suggesting, is for you to take the API from mpesa site http://www.safaricom.co.ke/business/sme/m-pesa-payment-solutions/m-pesa-api
and build a middle ware for your application.

Pointers: Check out the B2C and C2B- paybill and lipa na mpesa documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**M-PESA API Online Checkout Java / Android How to**

Following release of M-PESA API, you will need to create a web service client that does SOAP requests and process responses from API calls

I will provide a quick start guide for java developers geared towards integrating existing  Java applications.

**Pre-requisites**

JDK 7 or latest

**Instruction steps**

Download Full M-PESA API Guide from safaricom website
Read through Developers Guide C2B_OnlineCheckout_V2.0.doc
Generate JAX-WS artifacts . Your client will use this api to access the published  web service. 
Generate JAX-WS artifacts
We will use wsimport tool is used to parse checkout WSDL file and generate required files.

```
mkdir src

wsimport -XadditionalHeaders -clientjar safaricom-lipanampesa-onlinecheckout-wsdl.jar -s src -p ke.co.makara.integration.mpesa.lnmocheckout http://safaricom.co.ke/mpesa_online/lnmo_checkout_server.php?wsdl
```

Check wsimport --help to understand above options; 
Note the package directory for generated artefacts. WSDL is hosted on the lipa na M-PESA endpoint. For this purpose we use the production url. -clientjar option, new in Java 7, simplifies things. You would otherwise have to use -wsdllocation /META-INF/wsdl/Checkout.wsdl option. And copy the wsdl in META-INF after to mitigate the Java 6 wsimport limitation. See limitation below.
Optionally create source jar
While inside src folder run command.

```
jar cvf safaricom-lipanampesa-onlinecheckout-source-wsdl.jar ke/
```

Next we use the web service artifacts to invoke the web service from a web service client.

**Generated artifacts**

Service Endpoint Interface (SEI) - LNMOPortType.java
Service class - LnmoCheckoutService.java
If a wsdl:fault is present in the WSDL, an Exception class
Java classes mapped from schema types eg ProcessCheckOutRequest.java
If a wsdl:message is present in WSDL, asynchronous response beans eg ProcessCheckOutResponse.java

**Web Service Client**

Next we use the web service artifacts to invoke the web service from a web service client.
This can be a servlet invoked from front-end. Out of scope. For simplicity I will create a java class ~ a standalone console

Create a java class say LNMOCheckoutTester
In the Java client application, create an instance of the LnmoCheckoutService service

```
LnmoCheckoutService lnmoCheckoutService = new LnmoCheckoutService(); // lina na mpesa online checkout instance
```

The Service class will be created during the build.
Obtain a proxy to the service from the service using the getLnmoCheckout() method

```
LNMOPortType soap = lnmoCheckoutService.getLnmoCheckout();
```

The port carries the protocol binding and service endpoint address information. 
Configure the service endpoint
Configure the request context properties on the javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider interface

```
((BindingProvider)soap).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url + "lnmo_checkout_server.php"); // specifying this property on the RequestContext
```

JAX-WS provides support for the dynamic invocation of service endpoint operations.
I store the web service url in database and append the wsdl endpoint to this url. This configures the endpoint at runtime. 
Compose our client request M-PESA checkout message 
This is the message payload

```
ProcessCheckOutRequest checkOutRequest = objFactory.createProcessCheckOutRequest();
  checkOutRequest.setMERCHANTTRANSACTIONID("54635469064");
  checkOutRequest.setREFERENCEID("TD346534GH");
  checkOutRequest.setAMOUNT(13300);
  checkOutRequest.setMSISDN("0721XXXXXX");
  checkOutRequest.setENCPARAMS("");
  checkOutRequest.setCALLBACKURL("https://makara.co.ke:8443/odt/checkout");
  checkOutRequest.setCALLBACKMETHOD("GET");
  checkOutRequest.setTIMESTAMP(String.valueOf(date.getTime()));
```

Configure request headers
Follow business rules in Safaricom document to build the password. See attached code.
For String merchantId, String passkey, Date requestTimeStamp; Convert the concatenated string to bytes, Hash the bytes to get arbitary binary data and Convert the binary data to string use base64

```
CheckOutHeader requestHeader = objFactory.createCheckOutHeader();
  requestHeader.setMERCHANTID(MERCHANT_ID);
  Date timestamp = new Date();
  String encryptedPassword = getEncryptedPassword(MERCHANT_ID, PASSKEY, timestamp);
  requestHeader.setPASSWORD(encryptedPassword.toUpperCase());
  requestHeader.setTIMESTAMP(String.valueOf(timestamp.getTime()));
```

Invoke the service endpoint with the <s>dispatch</s> stab-based client
soap.processCheckOut(checkOutRequest, requestHeader);
Process the response message from the service as per your business requirement

```
  ProcessCheckOutResponse checkOutResponse = new ProcessCheckOutResponse();
  checkOutResponse.getRETURNCODE();
  checkOutResponse.getDESCRIPTION();
  checkOutResponse.getTRXID();
  checkOutResponse.getCUSTMSG();
```

**Tracing SOAP Traffic**

One of the usual steps involved in the debugging of Web Services applications is to inspect the request and response SOAP messages
Configure client to dump requests and response with JAX-WS 
    System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");

**Source code**

```
/*
 * LNMOCheckoutTester.java
 *
 * Nov 20, 2016 Joseph Makara -  Created File to tester Lina Na M-PESA Online checkout
 *
 *
 */
package testMe;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.xml.ws.*;
import ke.co.makara.integration.mpesa.lnmocheckout.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.*;

/**
 * @author Joseph Makara
 *
 */
public class LNMOCheckoutTester {

 private static final String PASSKEY = "234fdsghfsg5654dgfhgf6dsfdsafsd43dgfhdgfdgfh74567";
 private static final String MERCHANT_ID = "678fsgd54354";
 private static final String REFERENCE_ID = "";
 private static final String ENDPOINT_URL = "https://safaricom.co.ke/mpesa_online/";
 private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "https://makara.co.ke:8443/odt/checkout";
 private static final String CALLBACK_METHOD = "GET";


 static {
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
   @Override
   public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    if (hostname.equals("safaricom.co.ke")) return true;
    return false;
   }
  });
 }

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  LNMOPortType soap = outBoundLNMOCheckout(ENDPOINT_URL);

  ObjectFactory objFactory = new ObjectFactory();

  CheckOutHeader requestHeader = objFactory.createCheckOutHeader();
  requestHeader.setMERCHANTID(MERCHANT_ID);
  Date timestamp = new Date();
  String encryptedPassword = getEncryptedPassword(MERCHANT_ID, PASSKEY, timestamp);
  requestHeader.setPASSWORD(encryptedPassword);
  requestHeader.setTIMESTAMP(String.valueOf(timestamp.getTime()));

  ProcessCheckOutRequest checkOutRequest = objFactory.createProcessCheckOutRequest();
  checkOutRequest = processCheckOut(timestamp);

  soap.processCheckOut(checkOutRequest, requestHeader);

  ProcessCheckOutResponse checkOutResponse = new ProcessCheckOutResponse();
  checkOutResponse.getRETURNCODE();
  checkOutResponse.getDESCRIPTION();
  checkOutResponse.getTRXID();
  checkOutResponse.getENCPARAMS();
  checkOutResponse.getCUSTMSG();
 }

 private static ProcessCheckOutRequest processCheckOut(Date date){

  ProcessCheckOutRequest checkOutRequest = new ProcessCheckOutRequest();
  checkOutRequest.setMERCHANTTRANSACTIONID("54635469064");
  checkOutRequest.setREFERENCEID("TD346534GH");
  checkOutRequest.setAMOUNT(3.45);
  checkOutRequest.setMSISDN("0721826284");
  checkOutRequest.setENCPARAMS("");
  checkOutRequest.setCALLBACKURL(CALLBACK_URL);
  checkOutRequest.setCALLBACKMETHOD(CALLBACK_METHOD);
  checkOutRequest.setTIMESTAMP(String.valueOf(date.getTime()));

  return  checkOutRequest;
 }

 /**
  * Convert the concatenated string to bytes
  * Hash the bytes to get arbitary binary data
  * Convert the binary data to string use base64
  *
  * @param merchantId
  * @param passkey
  * @param date
  * @return
  */
 private static String getEncryptedPassword(String merchantId, String passkey, Date date) {
  String encodedPassword = null;
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(merchantId)
  .append(passkey)
  .append(date.getTime());

  try {
   String sha256 = getSHA256Hash(builder.toString());
   return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(sha256.getBytes("UTF-8")));;
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }

  return encodedPassword;
 }

 private static LNMOPortType outBoundLNMOCheckout(String url) {
  System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
  LnmoCheckoutService lnmoCheckoutService = new LnmoCheckoutService();
  LNMOPortType soap = lnmoCheckoutService.getLnmoCheckout();

  ((BindingProvider)soap).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
   url + "lnmo_checkout_server.php");

  return soap;
 }

 private static String getSHA256Hash(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
  MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
  byte[] result = mDigest.digest(input.getBytes());
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   sb.append(Integer.toString((result[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
  }
  return sb.toString();
 }

}
```

**Sample Soap Request**

```
[HTTP request - https://safaricom.co.ke/mpesa_online/lnmo_checkout_server.php]---
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035 svn-revision#5f6196f2b90e9460065a4c2f4e30e065b245e51e
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header>
        <ns2:CheckOutHeader xmlns:ns2="tns:ns">
            <MERCHANT_ID>F2678987M</MERCHANT_ID>
            <PASSWORD>QQFSOITZB5OJMJTW073/SCWLN5WMDL6LO0FP6DJZ8TQ=</PASSWORD>
            <TIMESTAMP>1479116220855</TIMESTAMP>
        </ns2:CheckOutHeader>
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:processCheckOutRequest xmlns:ns2="tns:ns">
            <MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_ID>54635469064</MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_ID>
            <REFERENCE_ID>TD346534GH</REFERENCE_ID>
            <AMOUNT>3.45</AMOUNT>
            <MSISDN>0721826284</MSISDN>
            <ENC_PARAMS></ENC_PARAMS>
            <CALL_BACK_URL>https://makara.co.ke:8443/odt/checkout</CALL_BACK_URL>
            <CALL_BACK_METHOD>lnmo</CALL_BACK_METHOD>
            <TIMESTAMP>1479116220855</TIMESTAMP>
        </ns2:processCheckOutRequest>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

You will only need to contact Safaricom to get Demo test org details (Merchant ID and PassKey)

[Client jar](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9UN1L0QA834QWdLcEdPWFRIOHM)

[Source code](https://unitechideas.blogspot.com.au/2016/11/lipa-na-mpesa-online-checkout-java.html)

Comment: this can't be used in android applications because some critical java libraries are not found in android

Comment: did you really test it in an android application?

Answer (score 1):

The M-Pesa API is currently a SOAP API and SOAP isn't native on Android so it's a bunch of work to integrate the API on your app. I wrote Chowder to help developers handle M-Pesa easily and here's all you have to do:

```
//Add a new dependency
dependencies {
    compile 'com.toe.chowder:chowder:0.7.6'
}
```

Create a Chowder instance:

```
//You can create a single global variable for Chowder like this
Chowder chowder = new Chowder(YourActivity.this, PAYBILL_NUMBER, PASSKEY, this);

//You can also add your callback URL using this constructor
Chowder chowder = new Chowder(YourActivity.this, PAYBILL_NUMBER, callbackUrl ,PASSKEY, this);
```

Process your payment:

```
//You can then use processPayment() to process individual payments
chowder.processPayment(amount, phoneNumber, productId);
```

Confirm payment:

```
chowder.checkTransactionStatus(PAYBILL_NUMBER, transactionId);
```

There's more sample code and a test Paybill number and passkey [here](https://github.com/IanWambai/Chowder).

Comment: How does one get this passkey?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a year ago but you may look at this if still not found a solution.

https://bitbucket.org/mwanzias/mpesaonlinecheckout/downloads/README.md

from here you will be able to post from the android application direct to the back end system that does the mpesa communication.

The demo described here gives  online checkout capabilities if you want it extended to B2C, B2B and C2B notifications then you may contact the owner.

you could also look at the following and see if you can fork and adapt it.

https://github.com/aksalj/pesajs

Comment: So you charge for this service

Comment: Kinene, For checkout no, unless you will use my servers but if you like it you will get it for your own use

Comment: How can one implement your jar in android? i can see an example. how can i download the jar, install it in my project and use it?